# App crash on UItable on iOS device not on simulator?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have a table view with some cells on it. When I tap on single-cell my app just gets crashed on the real iOS device but the app works fine on the simulator. Please tell me why the app crashing on a real device, not on the simulator.

Following is code for the app:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {

         UIStoryboard  *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
         UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BusinessCard"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
    else if(indexPath.row==1)
    {
        UIStoryboard  *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NonBusinessCard"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];


    }
    else if(indexPath.row==2)
    {
        UIStoryboard  *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EventCard"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

    }

}
```

Comment: Can we see the error it crashes with?

Comment: I am not able to see the logs because the device is not connected to xcode.I am using xcode 6.2 which shows my devices as ineligible device.@Yanchi

Comment: I would suggest to try create empty view controller instead of initializing from storyboard and see if it pushes empty controller. If it pushes, then error would be in your *storyboard or *vc initializations

Comment: App not crashing on simulator.It crash only on real device.

Comment: How to create empty view controller?Sorry i am beginner@Yanchi

Comment: What could be the issue you see here if app is getting crashed only on real device not on simulator?@Yanchi

Comment: You need to update to the latest non-beta version of Xcode. This is pretty much impossible to debug without connecting to a debugger. (I'm guessing you have the latest iOS and an older version of Xcode.)

Comment: Yes i have latest iOS & old xcode